# Spring MVC rest urls not working

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

I am working with Spring MVC and can get some simple urls to map to the correct controllers but not with restful dynamic urls. In my example, I have a uri, /agent. This is to be expanded to /agent/{name}. I have mapped this thusly in my controller:

```
public class AgentController implements Controller {

    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/agent/{name}")
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable String name)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        logger.info("Returning Agent view");        
        return new ModelAndView("agent.jsp", "name", name);
    }

    @Override
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest arg0,
        HttpServletResponse arg1) throws Exception {
        return null;
    }
}
```

My web.xml looks like:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Monitor</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Monitor</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/agents</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Monitor</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/agent/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>
        index.jsp
    </welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

and the Monitor-servlet.xml looks like:

```
<bean name="/agents" class="com.activoz.monitor.web.IndexController"/>
<bean name="/agent/*" class="com.activoz.monitor.web.AgentController"/>
```

The /agents url works fine and can display some data using hibernate but with /agent alone I get a blank which in my mind seems to be expected because of the overridden null returning handleRequest at the bottom. I am wondering however, why the /agent/Ping or /agent/Http is not being mapped to the top handleRequest method? I get this error when I try to pull up /Monitor/agent/Ping:

```
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Monitor/agent/Ping] in     DispatcherServlet with name 'Monitor'
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use only one servlet-mapping definition.  Delete the second servlet-mapping definition from web.xml, and use @RequestMapping definitions to control relationship between URL and function.

Comment: Thanks Felipe for the help. I changed this in web.xml and I still get the "The requested resource is not available error" in the browser (though nothing in the logs which to me is strange). Is possible my @RequestMapping needs to be changed too?

Comment: I put the @RequestMapping("/agent") at the top of public class AgentController and have the overridden handleRequest returning a jsp page. If I take the entry out of web.xml as suggested it doesn't work but if I leave it in, it works fine. The only thing still not working is the main issue "/agent/{name}". Any ideas about that possibly?